# How to avoid the toothbrush becoming harder and harder after a period of use?

Tags: personal-care

I recently find the more time you use your toothbrush, the harder it becomes! I've asked some people somewhere else and was told that it was because of the plasticiser leaching…… One thousand people will have one thosands answers...

I use toothpaste everyday and I will clear my toothbrush by water directly, my toothbrush is of Bamboo charcoal.

I really want to know:

1) Why? Will it do bad effects on my teeth?

2) How to avoid this?

Comment: Hi Beginner, Welcome to Lifehacks. I'm not sure this site is well-suited to answer such a question. Please review the [Tour] and [Help] to introduce you to the kinds of things best asked about here.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add more detail. What kind of toothbrush? Do you use dentifrice? What are the bristles made from? Do you rinse your toothbrush after use? Do you soak it? Have you consulted a dentist or dental assistant?

Comment: @Stan：I've updated my question now ;)

Comment: How long does it take for your toothbrush to become hard?

Comment: For what it's worth, toothbrushes should be [replaced every 3-4 months. The ends of the bristles lose their original shape and become less effective.](https://www.ada.org/en/member-center/oral-health-topics/toothbrushes) Perhaps by replacing your toothbrush regularly the bristles won't have time to harden.

Comment: @CaiusJard：About 3-4 months.

Comment: @BrettFromLA：Thanks but I feel a little curious——why it doesn't become soft but hard? And can I use warm water or something like vinegar to soften it?

Comment: @Beginner Sorry I don't know the answer to that. I'm sure the answer varies depending on what the bristles are made of!

Comment: Curious.  My toothbrushes always go soft with age, I've never had one go hard.

Answer (score 2):

You've indicated it takes about 3-4 months for your toothbrush to become hard. This is, coincidentally, the period for which dental professionals recommend is a the useful, healthy life of a toothbrush

Throw it away and buy another

Comment: Thanks but I feel a little curious——why it doesn't become soft but hard? And can I use warm water or something like vinegar to soften it to extend its life?